# Relatively Positioning drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website for a company and having a hard time with positioning. I want the drop-down menus to position either left or right based on where they are on the screen. Here's a screenshot of what happens currently: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZfWo.png)

Also, If you want to take a look at the live site, [here's](http://www.sagetechs.com/beta) a link to the demo.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Not to throw another confusing element in, but this particular site is responsive. When I go down to an Ipad size screen the problem get's worse.

Comment: div #main overflow is killing menu borders when open near the right

Comment: Unfortunately, when I remove that my footer has some strange overflow issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container is `960px`. The dropdown menu has an `auto` width so you'll need to estimate the width of each menu (let's say `200px`).

Now, you can use `document.body.offsetWidth` to determine the width of the browser window. This is what I would suggest:

```
function on_hover() {
    ...
    dropdown_width = 200;
    container_width = 960;
    if (document.body.offsetWidth < container_width + dropdown_width) {
        dropdown_from_left();
    } else {
        dropdown_from_right();
    }
    ...
}
```

Hopefully this is enough for you to get started. Enjoy and good luck!